# Nativescript prompt dialog select all text

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I was just wondering if it was possible to have a nativescript prompt dialog  select all of the text upon opening without going so far as to create an entire custom dialog.  I don't see any settings when creating it, but I was wondering if someone knew of a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native dialog controller or the UI components inside are private to the `dialogs` module, not exported for public use. Hence you will need a custom one in order to operate on the textfield.